# Why do I lose control of my ship near the Mun?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I built a ship and launched it into orbit, then set it on a trajectory for the Mun.  I accelerated time until the ship was near it.  At this point, the Mun was between my ship and Kerbin.  I went to do another maneuver in order to orbit the Mun, but the ship was nonresponsive.  I had plenty of fuel and battery, but the ship was completely inert.  I could not even open/close the storage bay I had.  The ship eventually continued on its path, and when I was near Kerbin again, I was able to operate the ship, run the engine, etc. perfectly.  Is there some range restriction from Kerbin outside of which your ship does not work?  Is there a module to fix this issue?  Or was it an isolated glitch?

Comment: Was this an autonomous ship? Or a crewed ship?

Comment: It was crewed.  By http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Jebediah_Kerman

Comment: So first off, are you using 1.2? If you are, is the ship being _controlled_ by a probe core? Just because there's a Kerbal on board doesn't mean they're controlling the ship.

Comment: I had the same thing happen only to realize I was actually still warped without realizing. When I hit the < key to cancel warp, my ship was completely responsive again.

Comment: Yep, cant tell you how many times ive fallen for the "still in warp, why cant I control anything" trap.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I reproduced the problem last night... I was still warping time a little bit.

Oops. :(

The reason the ship started working again near Kerbin is that the game automatically disables the time warp at that point.

Comment: Well, that clarifies things a lot. Thanks! Yes, the game brings you out of warp mode when your ship enters a different Sphere of Influence (SOI).

Comment: @Ricardo I believe it's only when under a certain height from a certain celestial body. For example you can't time warp past 1x under... 40 km around Kerbin? I'm not sure, but it's not when entering a SOI. In fact, it's advisable to manually reduce time warp when changing SOI to prevent some random physics bugs that may alter your trajectory.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer - You're right! From what I recall, it just slows down the warp factor when entering a new SOI, but doesn't reduces it all the way. It must be one of the reduction rules under a given altitude as you mentioned. I remember also that I got dewarped when crossing Kerbin atmosphere (at 70km) at either direction, when it reduces time warp all the way down, but I may be wrong here, too. It's just too many details...

Comment: @Ricardo Basically, each height has its own maximum time warp. Even at 150 km from Kerbin you can't time warp at 1000x.